# Does anyone have any simple JEXL examples using a loop. I am looking to iterate around a simple Array to output various string values?

Tags: java, jexl

Does anyone have any simple JEXL examples using a loop.  I am looking to iterate around a simple object arraylist to output various string values?

Answer (score 6):

A full example with input for 452' is here :

> ```
> public static void testSimpleList() {
>
>         List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
>         list.add("one");
>         list.add("two");
>
>
>         JexlContext jexlContext = new MapContext();
>         jexlContext.set("list", list);;
>
>         Map<String, Object> functions1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>         functions1.put("system", System.out);
>
>
>         JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
>         jexl.setFunctions(functions1);
>         Expression expression = jexl.createExpression("for(item : list) { system:println(item) }");
>
>
>         expression.evaluate(jexlContext);
>
>
>     }
> ```

Output :

> ```
> one
> two
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it requires one to use script instead of expression.

This fails with error "parsing error in 'for'"

```
e = new org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlBuilder().create();
c = new org.apache.commons.jexl3.MapContext();
c.set("a", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
e.createExpression("for(x : a) { b=x }").evaluate(c)
```

This, however, works

```
e.createScript("for(x : a) { b=x }").evaluate(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through items of an Array, Collection, Map, Iterator or Enumeration, e.g.

```
for(item : list) {
    x = x + item; 
}
```

Where item and list are variables. The JEXL 1.1 syntax using foreach(item in list) is now deprecated.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.jexl2.Expression;
import org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlContext;
import org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine;
import org.apache.commons.jexl2.MapContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JexlContext jexlContext = new MapContext();
        Map<String, Object> functions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        functions.put("system", System.out);
        JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
        jexl.setFunctions(functions);
        Expression expression = jexl.createExpression("for(item : list) { system:println(item) }");
        expression.evaluate(jexlContext);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: should use createScript() instead of createExpression() using version 3.1

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost thing, you should use **Script evaluator**, instead of **Expression evaluator**. Expression evaluators do not support complex looping syntax. Refer [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jexl3/package-summary.html)

> **JexlScript**
>
> These allow you to use multiple statements and you can use variable
>   assignments, loops, calculations, etc. More or less what can be
>   achieved in Shell or JavaScript at its basic level. The result from
>   the last command is returned from the script.
>
> **JxltEngine.Expression**
>
> These are ideal to produce "one-liner" text, like a 'toString()' on
>   steroids. To get a calculation you use the EL-like syntax as in
>   ${someVariable}. The expression that goes between the brackets behaves
>   like a JexlScript, not an expression. You can use semi-colons to
>   execute multiple commands and the result from the last command is
>   returned from the script. You also have the ability to use a 2-pass
>   evaluation using the #{someScript} syntax.

**Try this instead,**

```
JexlScript jexlExpression = jexl.createScript("var x='';for(item:[1,2,3]){ x=x+item;}");

jexlExpression.evaluate(jexlContext);
```

Once this will work for you, you can use your own Array as well.